# Copy column from previous sheet and append at specific index Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a 3-sheet xlsx file, and I need to copy one certain column from previous sheet and append to the next on at specific index (in between already existed columns, so I suppose I need also create this column and "move" existed data to the right side).
I know how to get one specific value from cell, but I have no idea how I can copy and paste this column programmatically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert column using openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826305/insert-column-using-openpyxl)

Comment: Use `zip`. There was a similar discussion about this on the mailing list some time back.