# unable to insert a blank column in openpyxl using cell coordinates

Tags: python, openpyxl

i am not able to find any method in openpyxl that allows for inserting a new blank column with a known column letter or index from current cell properties.  for instance, if i am searching through cells on rows and find a cell that has cell.column value of "E" and want to insert a new column before column E, i don't see any function or method for inserting a new column within openpyxl.  is this possible at all or is there any known working method for doing so ?

UPDATE:
so i tried the test code as is from [Insert column using openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826305/insert-column-using-openpyxl) .
and it fails on following lines. i'm using python 2.7 and openpyxl 2.4.8

File "C:/Users/me/Desktop/my.py", line 30, in 
    column_letter, row = coordinate_from_string(coordinate)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\utils\cell.py", line 45, in coordinate_from_string
    match = COORD_RE.match(coord_string.upper())
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'upper'

Comment: i just updated my post with trying the test code from the answered link provided but ran into issues.

Answer (score 0):

Looping could shuffle values to the right, but you already knew that. I assume you weren't happy with cycles spent on interpretive overhead to copy in that way. It might look like:

```
for src, dst in zip(ws['E:Y'], ws['F:Z']):
    dst.value = src.value
```

There is [support for pandas dataframes](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/pandas.html). Consider turning worksheet into a df, inserting a column, then spitting out a new .xlsx.

Using array slicing with a [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) may prove simpler.

None of this deals with the sticky wicket of adjusting formula references.

Comment: i tried but get error "dst.value = src.value
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value' " .. if i look at src and dst they seem to have tuple of the cells i was just testing in a test spreadsheet with src of 'C:E' and dst of 'D:F'

Comment: You may need to wrap an outer loop around that. So 1st iteration: `zip(ws['Z:Z'], ws['Y:Y'])`, next iteration: `zip(ws['Y:Y'], ws['X:X'])`, and so on up to `E:E`.